# Custom Attribute to initialize other sealed attribute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium

Is it possible to somehow initialize *sealed* attribute from other (custom) attribute?

The reason is simple. I'm writing a **Data-Driven Unit Test** project with **Selenium Grid**. My **goal** is to write only tests and use *datasource* to **control** currently **tested browsers**. (I want to avoid writing `k*n` tests, where `n` are tests and `k` are supported browsers, where each test specify required `WebDriver`.)

This solution works for me very well, but it requires to declare all methods like this:

```
[TestMethod, DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\BrowserSelector.csv", "BrowserSelector#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("BrowserSelector.csv")]
public void TestMethod()
{
    // implementation
}
```

As you can see, parameters to a `DataSource` are really long. I can write it over multiple lines, which would improve readibility, but it doesn't solve my main problem: I'm **expecting** a lot of tests (easily **500+** - it is for a large business app) and I'd like to **avoid** unnecesarry and **redundant** attribute **definition**.

My idea was something like:

```
[TestMethod, MyDS, MyDep]
public void TestMethod()
{
    // implementation
}
```

where attribute `MyDS` will fill `DataSource`'s parameters automatically and in one place. I can't use *inheritance*, since `DataSourceAttribute` is **sealed**.

So, is it possible to avoid redundant attribute declation to my testing methods using custom attribute?

Comment: Checking documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute.aspx#Anchor_7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't think of any way to do what you're asking, but why not add your data source settings to app.config:

```
<microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>  
    <dataSources>  
        <add name="MyDataSource" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\\BrowserSelector.csv" dataTableName="BrowserSelector#csv" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>  
    </dataSources>  
</microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
```

And then set the attribute using [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243349.aspx)?

```
[TestMethod, DataSource("MyDataSource")]
public void TestMethod()
{
    // implementation
}
```

That should save you some typing.

More info at [Walkthrough: Using a Configuration File to Define a Data Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243192.aspx).